# How to remove a string from an array based on string matching id

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, checkbox

I'm currently rendering a Checkbox where if checked, the data (id in a string) is saved in state. However I'm trying to put together the functionality for if the checkbox is unchecked, the data needs to be removed from the state (which is an array of strings).

I have come up with this solution however I don't think I am using .splice correctly or if that's the best option for me to use as it doesn't work.

```
<Checkbox
        onChange={(e) => {
          e.target.checked
            ? setSelectedStyles([...selectedStyles, s.id])
            : e.target.checked === false &&
              selectedStyles.map((id) => id === s.id)
            ? selectedStyles.splice(s.id)
            : console.log(`didn't work`)
        }}
      ></Checkbox>
```

To clarify, `selectedStyles` is an array of strings stored in state. `s.id` is the id (string) I'm checking against.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
onChange={(e) => {
  e.target.checked
  ? setSelectedStyles([...selectedStyles, s.id])
  : setSelectedStyles(selectedStyles.filter(x => x !== s.id))
}}
```

The `filter` method allows to **clone** the array while removing the needed item at the same time.

You should never mutate a React state like you attempted to do whith `splice`.